# How can I receive a request from remote request in Mule anypoint?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I am sending a request with XML Data to an anypoint URL after an order is created from my site. How can receive this data  and save it as file and upload to a ftp?

I am new in mulesoft. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you exposing it via `HTTP` endpoint?

If so then to receive response just save the `response payload.`

```
flowVars.response = #[message.payload]
```

Then write to ftp path using `ftp connector.`

show your Xml config to help further.

Comment: it is sending data as file input.for reason i can not read it. how can i get that data?